# How to get length of updated array using property in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variable-length-array

I created a variable to hold the total number of elements in the array using myArray.length.
Then I use myArray.push() to add an element to the array.

the original array has 3 elements, so the .length returns 3, which is correct. But when I added an element to the array and I console.log(the Var which contains the .length property ), it just does not work. the Var still shows 3 for the array. However, if I use xxx.length, the number is correct now.

```js
var collection = function() {
  //two properties
  var items = ["basketball", "football", "soccer"];
  var number = items.length;

  console.log(items);
  console.log("the number of the items in the array is " + number);

  // two private methods
  var addItem = function(newItem) {
    items.push(newItem);
    console.log(items);
  };

  var showNumber = function() {
    console.log(number) //this one returns 3, which is not correct
    console.log("the number of the items in the array is " + items.length);
  }; // this one returns 4, which is correct



  // two public methods
  return {
    getItem: addItem,
    getNumber: showNumber,
  };
}();


collection.getItem("pingpong");
collection.getNumber();
```

Comment: `number` contains the value that `items.length` had. It is not a reference to `items.length`. Try updating `number` inside `addItem`?

Comment: you need to update `number` value in the `addItem` method.

Comment: Sounds like a good reason to _not_ introduce such an extra property. You have access to the count via `items.length` already, so _why_ invent your own property just to "mirror" that value?

Comment: As others have already mentioned, the value in `number` is never updated after you initially set it. It doesn't get updated just because you add something to the array. Just return `items.length` from your `getNumber()` function and it will always be accurate.